# I want to bring table header to next page if there is no space for single row to print with table header using wkhtmltopdf tool?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, header, wkhtmltopdf

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfbJQm.png]

I have added a screenshot of sample output, in which the table header is the previous page and the first row is on the next page. My expected output is if there is no space for a single row to print with a header then it should move to next page.

I have entered the code in the link. [Click here--](https://codepen.io/samgodil/pen/GRgaWNb)https://codepen.io/samgodil/pen/GRgaWNb`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with - https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_print_pagebb.asp

```
<style>
@media print
{
h1 {page-break-before:always}
}
</style>
```